# Powershell script to copy files to folders by matching file to folder names

Tags: powershell

I have a directory with empty folders, let's call it D1. And another directory (let's call it D2) with files which are named such that the file name contains the folder names from D1. I want to match the file names from D2 to folder names from D1 and copy (not move) the files to the corresponding folder in D1. Can this be done using Powershell? As an example,
D1 looks like:

```
FolderName1
FolderName2
FolderName3
```

And files in D2 look like:

```
abcd.FolderName1.txt
xyz.FolderName2.txt
qwerty.FolderName3.txt
```

EDIT: the folder names above are just an example. The actual folder/file names could vary e.g. to `Folder#Name`, `My_Folder`, `abcd.1234.Folder_Name` etc.

Comment: The answer is "yes", it can be done using PowerShell :) Have you tried... anything?

Comment: I have been doing `$sourceDir = "\D2\Files"
$targetDir = "\D1"
robocopy $sourceDir $targetDir *.bcp /e` which moves the files to the main target directory (only want to move `.bcp`s). But I don't know how to match the names in a loop and move to individual sub-folders. Sorry very new to `powershell`

Answer (score 1):

I pulled the folder names from the filename with regex.
There's a little bit of error handling in there, but you might want to instead create the folder if it doesn't exist.

```
$FromPath = 'C:\D2'
$ToPath = 'C:\D1'

$FilesToMove = Get-ChildItem -Path $FromPath -File

$RegexPattern = '^[^.]+\.(?<NewFolder>[^.]+)\..+$'

foreach ($File in $FilesToMove) {
    If($File.Name -match $RegexPattern){
        $OutFolder = Join-Path -Path $ToPath -ChildPath $Matches.NewFolder
        if (Test-Path -Path $OutFolder) {
            Copy-Item -Path $File -Destination $OutFolder
        }
        else {
            Write-Error -Message "Invalid or Inaccesible path $OutFolder"
        }
    }
    else {
        Write-Error -Message "Filename $($File.Name) Is Incorrectly Formatted"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @OwlsSleeping! It seems to work only in a very specific scenario when the folders and files are called `FolderNamex`, `x` being a number. If the folder name changes even slightly, e.g. to `Folder_Name1` or `My#Folder`, it doesn't work

Comment: I've added an edit to the question to avoid the confusion.

Comment: How are you meant to find the folder name from the file name without knowing the layout of the file name?

Comment: The folder name is always going to be contained in the file name

Comment: So maybe the direction of the search can be reversed i.e. instead of extracting the folder name from the file name and then trying to find it in the list of folders, the script can take the name of each folder and try to find it in the list of files. And then copy accordingly. If that makes sense?

Comment: Yes it's possible the other way. Feel free to post an answer to your own question after reversing it, or ask a new one if you get errors.

Comment: Cool will give that a shot